# Laravel set dynamically timezone for one Controller

Tags: laravel, timezone, laravel-5

i am developing website on Laravel. I set the default timezone in the `config/app.php`, but i have one section where the information there must be shown regarding the user timezone. Is there an option for one specific controller to use the user timezone ?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You can do stuff like `$user->created_at->setTimezone('America/New_York')` to convert a date from your application's timezone to a (potentially user-provided) timezone value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `config()` helper to set config values at any point in your request. This change affects that request only.

So, in your case, one option would be to update the config setting inside the constructor to your controller. Then, any requests that are handled by that controller will use the updated timezone setting.

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        config(['app.timezone' => 'America/Chicago']);
    }
}
```

You can move that statement pretty much anywhere as more global or granular control is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show local time for every user and you use Laravel dates (Carbon), you can do something like this:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    $object->created_at->setTimezone(Auth::user->timezone)
}
```